# Why do I get "Error in Sys.setenv(R_MAKEVARS_USER = NULL) : wrong length for argument" error when trying to build a STAN model?

Tags: r, windows, rstan

I am running Windows 10, and have R version `4.2.0`, with RTools installed for that version, and Rstan `2.21.5`. When I try running the following code, I get this error:

```
Error in Sys.setenv(R_MAKEVARS_USER = NULL) : wrong length for argument
```

From what I understand, there are caveats with compiling Rstan and RTools that can affect this, but I haven't been able to figure out if that's at play here or not.

In case this is code-related, this is what I try running

```
library(rstan)
options(mc.cores=4)

N=100
x = rbeta(N, 0.9, 0.9)

# where the error occurs
model = stan_model('D:\\my\\directory\\beta_fit.stan')

input_data = list(N=N, x=x)

fit = sampling(model, input_data, iter=200, chains=4)
```

Stan File:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  real<lower=0,upper=1> x[N];
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0> alpha;
  real<lower=0> beta;
}

model {
  alpha ~ lognormal(0, 5);
  beta ~ lognormal(0,5);
  for (i in 1:N){
    x[i] ~ beta(alpha,beta);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has likely to do with the configuration of the C++ toolchain.
Follow the instructions related to that at https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started#configuring-c-toolchain 
I had the same error and this worked for me, hope this helps.